# Call Unmanaged code from managed or spawn process

Tags: c#, .net, c++, unmanaged

I have an unmanaged C++ exe that I could call from inside my C# code directly (have the C++ code that I could make a lib) or via spawning a process and grabbing the data from the OutputStream.  What are the advantages/disadvantages of the options?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have source code of the C++ library, you can use C++/CLI to compile it into a mixed mode dll so it is easy to be used by the C# application.

The benefit of this will be most flexible on data flow (input or output to that C++ module).

While running the C++ code out of process has one benefit. If your C++ code is not very robust, this can make your main C# process stable so as not to be crashed by the C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

The big downside to scraping the OutputStream is the lack of data typing. I'd much rather do the work of exporting a few functions and reusing an existing library; but, that's really just a preference.

Answer (score 0):

Another disadvantage of spawning a process is that on windows spwaning a process is a very expensive (slow) operation. If you intend to call the c++ code quite often this is worth considering. 
An advantage can be that you're automatically more isolated to crashes in the c++ program. 
Drop in replacement of the c++ executable can be an advantage as well. 
Furthermore writing interop code can be big hassle in c#. If it's a complicated interace and you decide to do interop, have a look at c++/cli for the interop layer.

Answer (score 0):

You're far better off taking a subset of the functions of the C++ executable and building it into a library. You'll keep type safety and you'll be able to better leverage Exception Handling (not to mention finer grain control of how you manage the calls into the functions in the library).

If you go with grabbing the data from the OutputStream of the executable, you're going to have no visibility into the processes of the executable, no real exception handling, and you're going to lose any type information you may have had.

Answer (score 0):

The main disadvantage to being in process would be making sure you handle the managed/native interactions correctly.

1)

The c++ code will probably depend on deterministic destruction for cleanup/resource freeing etc.  I say probably because this is common and good practice in c++.

In the managed code this means you have to be careful to dispose of your c++ cli wrapper code properly.  If your code is used once, a using clause in c# will do this for you.  If the object needs to live a while as a member you'll find that the dispose will need to be chained the whole way through your application.

2)

Another issue depends on how memory hungry your application is.  The managed garbage collector can be lazy.  It is guaranteed to kick in if a managed allocation needs more space than is available.  However the unmanaged allocator is not connected in anyway.  Therefore you need to manaully inform the managed allocator that you will be making unmanaged allocations and that it should keep that space available.  This is done using the AddMemoryPressure method.

The main disadvantages to being out of process are:

1) Speed.

2) Code overhead to manage the communication.

3) Code overhead to watch for one or other process dying when it is not expected to.